# AngularJs $parse string to object

Tags: javascript, angularjs-1.5

So lets say I have a server that returns a string like:

```
{
    add:function(a,b) {
        return a+b;
    },
    subtract:function(a,b) {
        return a-b;
    }   
}
```

is it possible to $parse that into a function?

I tryed to parse it with:

```
$parse(element.Content) // Content is the string above
```

but get

```
Token '{' is an unexpected token
```

I would like something like:

```
elementFunctions = $parse(element.Content)
```

Comment: why would you ever store code that you plan to execute in variables?  This is an extremely dangerous practice, and isn't particularly practical.

Answer (score 0):

`$parse` does not do what you think it does!

To put it simply, it just **resolves** properties, by their name, against some context (angular **scopes**) -- basically.
Well, it's more than that, it provides a way to interact with these properties, but you'll get the gist of it by having a quick look at [its documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse]).

---

It does not **evaluate** `String`s as javascript code.

You're most likely looking to `eval`uate your `string`.
***Although in many, many cases*** there's a better, faster, more controllable and more reasonable solution!

```js
const code = ''
+   'const functions = {'
+       'add: function(a,b) {'
+           'return a+b;'
+       '},'
+       'subtract: function(a,b) {'
+           'return a-b;'
+       '}'
+   '};'
+   'functions';

console.log(eval(code).add(50, 1));
```